# Git push results in "Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: git

I have been using Github for a little while and I have been fine with git add, git commit, and git push so far with no problems. Suddenly I am having an error that says:

> > fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> >
> > Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> >     and the repository exists.

In the terminal, I have to redo the ssh-keygen 5 times already keep on getting this error message in the terminal. Also, I have done doing HTTP also but every time get:

> > > fatal: Authentication failed for the repository.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this problem is and how I can fix it? I just don't know what to do now so angry

Comment: Multiple things could cause this. Do you actually have access? Does your ssh key match? Is ssh using the correct key?

Answer (score 4):

Since [GitHub status](https://www.githubstatus.com/) is green (nominal), the issue is on your side.

ssh-keygen will only influence repositories cloned with an SSH URL.
Check first you have correctly registered the public key with

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

For HTTP, check if you have credentials cached with `git config credential.helper`